# Prompt user for additional information during an Open Id Connect event?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, owin, openid-connect

Using asp.net Core, Mvc and OpenIdConnect, is it possible to prompt an authenticated user for additional information during the ODIC authentication process, and then redirect back to the originally-desired page?

To give a concrete example: in our system one person, represented by an email address, can have multiple user ids that they may wish to operate under.  Assume my email address is tregan@domain.com, and I have 3 user ids to choose from: treganCat, treganDog, treganMouse. When I hit a Controller action that is decorated with the [Authorize] attribute I first go through OpenIdConnect authentication, and one of the claims returned is an email address.

Using that email address, I want the application to prompt me to select the identity that I want to run under (treganDog, treganCat, or treganMouse).

From there, I want the application to take the user id that I selected, interrogate a database for the roles that go along with the selected user id, and load those roles as claims to my identity.

Finally, I want the application to send me on to my desired page (which is the protected Controller method that I originally attempted to visit).

Is this possible?

I'm using an Owin Startup class; the code below "works" except for the fictional line "var identityGuid = [return value from the prompt];" ("fictional" because it represents what I would like to occur, but in fact a series of redirects would be needed).

My example below uses the OnTicketReceived event, but that selection is arbitrary, I would be willing to do this in any event.

```
        services.AddAuthentication(authenticationOptions =>
            {
                authenticationOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                authenticationOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddCookie()
            .AddOpenIdConnect(openIdConnectOptions =>
            {
                openIdConnectOptions.Authority = Configuration["PingOne:Authority"];
                openIdConnectOptions.CallbackPath = "/Callback";
                openIdConnectOptions.ClientId = Configuration["PingOne:ClientId"];
                openIdConnectOptions.ClientSecret = Configuration["PingOne:ClientSecret"];
                openIdConnectOptions.ResponseType = "code";

                openIdConnectOptions.Events.OnTicketReceived = (ticketReceivedContext) =>
                {                   
                    var emailClaim =
                        ticketReceivedContext.Principal.Claims.FirstOrDefault(o =>
                            o.Type == ClaimTypes.Email);
                    string emailAddress = emailClaim.Value;

                    //here is where I would like to prompt the user to select an identity based on the email address
                    //the selected identity is represented by a guid
                    var identityGuid = [return value from the prompt];

                   var roles = new MyRepository(myContext).GetRolesForUserId(identityGuid);

                    var claims = new List<Claim>();
                    foreach (string role in roles)
                    {
                        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));
                    }

                    ticketReceivedContext.Principal.AddIdentity(new ClaimsIdentity(claims));
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                };

            });
```

Comment: To me this looks as if you should use 2 totally separate methods. OIDC *Authenticates* the user, and your desired impersonation is basically a form of *Authorization*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what I want to do is simply not possible without either figuring out a way to do it inside PingOne or writing my own IdentityServer and taking care of the extra steps there.

I decided to instead write a custom middleware that fires after the Authentication middleware, as described in this SO question: [In asp.net core, why is await context.ChallengeAsync() not working as expected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59379370/in-asp-net-core-why-is-await-context-challengeasync-not-working-as-expected)

Answer (score 0):

This is impersonation where there is a real user and you need to identify the impersonated user after login.

You will need to complete the login first, return to the app and configure the principal. Then render a UI and receive the selected choice.

You then need your UI to call the back end and tell it to update claims in the auth cookie. Not sure if you'll get this to work though - the impersonated user may need separate storage - such as a second cookie.

This highlights that it can be useful to separate the token / credential the UI receives from the claims the back end works with.

I use the below design a lot for REST APIs that serve UIs directly - though it may be overkill for your solution:
https://authguidance.com/2017/10/03/api-tokens-claims/